# pandas read_csv import gives mixed type for a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that contains 130,000 rows.  After reading in the file using pandas' read_csv function, one of the Column("CallGuid") has mixed object types.

I did:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
```

Then I have this:

```
In [10]: df["CallGuid"][32767]
Out[10]: 4129237051L    

In [11]: df["CallGuid"][32768]
Out[11]: u'4129259051'
```

All rows <= 32767 are of type `long` and all rows > 32767 are `unicode`

Why is this?

Comment: Have you checked that row in your original csv? It could be quoted or have some other issue, what happens if you do `df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", skiprows=32768)` is the dtype wrong?

Comment: @EdChum after I put in skiprows=32768 I lost the column names, which were in row 0, how do I keep the header row?

Comment: do `skiprows=[32768]`. You skipped the first 32768 rows without the `[]`

Comment: after `skiprows=[32768]`, I still have `df["CallGuid"][32767]` as `long` and `df["CallGuid"][32768]` as `unicode`

Comment: The point being is whether the original data is ill formed, you need to check whether the original csv has ill formed data, otherwise you could fix this after loading by doing `df[CallGuid'] = df['CallGui'].astype(int64)`

Comment: I duplicated row 32767 so that I have the same record at row 32767 & 32768 and did a read_csv. Now I have row 32767 as `long` and row 32768 as `unicode`.  But they are the same record!

Comment: what happens with: `df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", dtype={'CallGuid': int})`?

Comment: @PaulH strange, I got an `OverflowError` after putting in `dtype={'CallGuid': int}`, I thought python can handle arbitrarily big numbers

Comment: Hmm. Try numpy.int64 instead of int

Comment: @PaulH same overflow error, `long` didn't work neither, the number in question is 4155661665031820141956

Comment: what version of pandas are you using? Can't reproduce longs being created at all in 0.14.1. You're going to have an issue here since that's larger than typemax int64 (and I can't see how whether you can even use int128 with numpy)

Comment: @AndyHayden don't have access to my computer now, will let you know the pandas version on Monday

Comment: @AndyHayden my pandas version is 0.14.0

Comment: would be great to see an example csv which reproduces this. suspect it's to do with 32767 being max of int16... i.e. first bit of pass finds only int64 so uses that, next chunk finds an object (long, too big for int64) so uses object.

Comment: @AndyHayden that's probably the reason.  For the time being, I converted the column to strings.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

As others have pointed out, your data could be malformed, like having quotes or something...

Just try doing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", dtype={"CallGuid": np.int64})
```

It's also more memory efficient, since pandas doesn't have to guess the data types.

Answer (score 2):

OK I just experienced the same problem, with the same symptom : df[column][n] changed type after n>32767

I indeed had a problem in my data, but not at all at line 32767

Finding and modifying these few problematic lines solved my problem.
I managed to localize the line that was problematic by using the following extremely dirty routine :

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',chunksize = 10000)
i=0
for chunk in df:
    print "{} {}".format(i,chunk["Custom Dimension 02"].dtype)
    i+=1
```

I ran this and I obtained :

```
0 int64
1 int64
2 int64
3 int64
4 int64
5 int64
6 object
7 int64
8 object
9 int64
10 int64
```

Which told me that there was (at least) one problematic line between 60000 and 69999  and one between 80000 and 89999

To localize them more precisely, you can just take a smaller chunksize and print only the number of the rows that do not have the correct dta type

Comment: I found this super useful! I now have this as part of my script and created an embedded loop that goes 1 by 1 with 100 chunks to redefine the correct dtype.